# Get exact match instead textContent.includes with Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html

Hi have a working JS function to add a div based on text inside an element, se below. In the example for something like

`<div class="class">sometext</div>`

This works well, but how do I make it for this exact match only, so it wont add the extra div if the element has another word (Which I know what it is)

Example where I dont want it to add the div:

`<div class="class">sometext remove</div>`

```
const descriptions = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
function showDescription() {
    for (const description of descriptions) {
        
        if (description.textContent.includes("sometext")) {
            description.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div></div>");
        }
    }
}
showDescription();
```

Comment: Why simple don't use `description.textContent === "sometext"` ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Btw If I want to add a match for two words, how do I extend it then?

Comment: if is just two you can do `description.textContent === "sometext" || description.textContent === "sometext2"` or you can loop an array and if match do insert. Look my answer.

Answer (score 0):

ou can use Regex for that :

```
const str = 'sometext';
const regex = /^word$/;
const containsSometext = regex.test(str);
```

here the ^ refers to the start of the string and $ refers to the end of it
containsSometext will return true if the est is true and false if not

Comment: Hi! Im aware I should use Regex or match etc, but unsure how to write it in the IF statement. Thanks though, something to work on :)

Comment: if containsSometext return true then it matches perfectly, if it returns false it doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `===` like:

```js
const descriptions = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
function showDescription() {
    for (const description of descriptions) {
        
        if (description.textContent === "sometext") {
            description.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div>newDiv</div>");
        }
    }
}
showDescription();
```

```html
<div class="class">sometext</div>
<div class="class">sometext2</div>
<div class="class">sometext</div>
<div class="class">sometext remove</div>
```

If you have two words you can use `||` with `===` or an array like:

1:

```js
const descriptions = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
function showDescription() {
    for (const description of descriptions) {
        
        if (description.textContent === "sometext" || description.textContent === "sometext2") {
            description.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div>newDiv</div>");
        }
    }
}
showDescription();
```

```html
<div class="class">sometext</div>
<div class="class">sometext2</div>
<div class="class">sometext</div>
<div class="class">sometext remove</div>
```

2:

```js
const descriptions = document.querySelectorAll(".class");
const textForDiv = ['sometext','sometext2'];
function showDescription() {
    for (const description of descriptions) {
        textForDiv.forEach(el => {
          if (description.textContent === el) {
            description.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div>newDiv</div>");
        }
        });        
    }
}
showDescription();
```

```html
<div class="class">sometext</div>
<div class="class">sometext2</div>
<div class="class">sometext</div>
<div class="class">sometext remove</div>
```

Comment: this may works fine but it needs more case management, I mean the upperCase and LowerCase that needs to be handled according to the use case, and also don't forget to trim the string

Comment: If the string must be the same equal (`===`) using `lowerCase/upperCase` is meaningless.

Comment: that's why I said according to the use case and how he wants to handle it, same thing for the trim, if he wants the spaces to have an effect he shouldn't add the trim feature

Comment: I know that's why I didn't put either of them :)